# What does the phrase “If there were more busses” mean?

Tags: conditional-constructions, conditionals

> If there **were** more buses, we **would** leave the car at home

What does this “If there were more buses” indicate? Does this mean a) we are imagining just about more buses  or b)It also suggests that it is unlikely that there will be more buses

Answer (score 1):

"If...were..." implies an unreal conditional sentence.

This is simply a concept that is being posited by the person.  (case "a", above).

It does not imply the likelihood of buses appearing in the future.

Comment: To put it more simply, the speaker is imagining a situation with a more frequent bus service (whether or not that is likely).